# Timestamp conversion clarification

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I created a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SAFFa/1/)

```
e.onclick=timeConverter('2014-05-02 22:03:34');  //IF I PASS THIS STRING AS DATE, I GOT THIS: 2,May 2014 22:3:34
e.onclick=timeConverter('2014-05-02T22:03:34.890Z'); //IF I PASS THIS STRING AS DATE, I GOT THIS: 3,May 2014 6:3:34
```

Does "T" or "Z" in the string matters? If someone can enlighten me, thank  you.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="format" value="Format Date">
```

Javascript:

```
function timeConverter(UNIX_timestamp){

    var s = new Date(UNIX_timestamp).getTime()/1000;   

    var a = new Date(s*1000);
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var year = a.getFullYear();
    var month = months[a.getMonth()];
    var date = a.getDate();
    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    var sec = a.getSeconds();
    var time = date+','+month+' '+year+' '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec ;

    //var time = date+','+month+' '+year+' '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec ;
    alert(time);

}

var e = document.getElementById('format');
e.onclick=timeConverter('2014-05-02 22:03:34');
//e.onclick=timeConverter('2014-05-02T22:03:34.890Z');
```

Comment: what's the matter here??

Comment: He's probably wondering why the dates are not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this document [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) which is a extract of ISO 8601.

`'T'` is just meant as separator between Time and Date.

`'Z'` is a special indicator for `UTC (+00:00)` as time zone

The Problem is, '`2014-05-02 22:03:34`' is kinda chrome specific formatting as far as i know, which treats this time as your local time. So the difference of exactly 8 hours appear.

So to be on the safe side, always remember to put the Separator in and keep in mind what timezone you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you for your clear response. I am in the process of converting it and got confused if I still need the "T" and "Z" in the string.

Answer (score 1):

see this [wiki-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) , the Z in your string means that you are using the
 local timezone, so thats the reason for the differnce in your alert

Comment: Deleting the z doesn't make a difference, that there are 2 different Dates then.

Comment: yes thats right, because of the "T" read the article ;) its because of your timezone

Answer (score 1):

According to [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), accepted datetime format is:

```
[+YY]YYYY[-MM[-DD]][THH:mm[:ss[.sss]]]Z
```

Where `Z` is either `Z` or `+` , `-` followed by `HH:mm`. If you specify Z at the end of your timestamp, it means the time is in UTC. Since you are living in GMT+8, your browser adds 8 hours to convert it to local time. Therefore, you get `3,May 2014 6:3:34` instead of `2,May 2014 22:3:34`.